# Magento2 credit card form is not populating with cvv and date filed

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, store-credit

Am Trying To Create A New Online Payment Gateway Module In Magento.

To Get Started Am Using Sample Payment Module Form Git Hub, 
My **Stripe.html**

```
<div class="payment-method" data-bind="css: {'_active': (getCode() == isChecked())}">
    <div class="payment-method-title field choice">
        <input type="radio"
               name="payment[method]"
               class="radio"
               data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()"/>
        <label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()"></span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="payment-method-content">
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('messages') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion(getBillingAddressFormName()) -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>

        <form class="form" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode() + '-form'}">
            <!-- ko template: 'Magento_Payment/payment/cc-form' --><!-- /ko -->
        </form>

        <div class="checkout-agreements-block">
            <!-- ko foreach: $parent.getRegion('before-place-order') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
        </div>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button class="action primary checkout"
                        type="submit"
                        data-bind="
                        click: placeOrder,
                        attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
                        css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
                        enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
                        "
                        disabled>
                    <span data-bind="text: $t('Place Order')"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**stripemethod.js**

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Payment/js/view/payment/cc-form',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Magento_Payment/js/model/credit-card-validation/validator'
    ],
    function (Component, $) {
        'use strict';

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Gssi_Icanpay/payment/stripe'
            },

            getCode: function() {
                return 'stripe';
            },

            isActive: function() {
                return true;
            },

            validate: function() {
                var $form = $('#' + this.getCode() + '-form');
                return $form.validation() && $form.validation('isValid');
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Now I Need Help On Showing Credit Card From In Checkout Page, Which Is By Default Not Available. I Have Used CC-Form But It is Not Showing cvv,Months And Year field.

Can any one help me on this problem? Any references or suggestions are highly appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You require js, that's why you are not getting cvv and labels. Check this js file : vendor\magento\module-payment\view\frontend\web\js\view\payment\cc-form.js and also etc->frontend-di.xml and follow the same as in payment module